# The Type of The Expression Must Be An Array Type But It Resolved To String | Java

Tags: java, string, boolean, minecraft, detect

Edit:

I have revised my code and gone to something a little more reliable, though I still have errors with my Player.

```
package me.kcsharkfin.commands;

import me.kcsharkfin.alreadysaid.AlreadySaid;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

public class HelpCommand implements CommandExecutor {

    private AlreadySaid plugin;

    public HelpCommand(AlreadySaid plugin) {
        this.plugin - plugin;
        plugin.getCommand("help").setExecutor(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        if (!(sender instanceof Player))
            sender.sendMessage("Only Players Have Permission to Execute This Command");
            return true;
    }

    Player p - (Player) sender;

    if (p.hasPermission("alreadysaid.command.help"))
        p.sendMessgae("Test");
        return true;
    } else {
        p.sendMessage("You Do Not Have Permision To Execute This Command!");
    }
    return false;
    }

}
```

That was my HelpCommand.class, I also had an AlreadySaid.class

```
  public void onEnable() {
    this.config = new Config(this);
    this.config.load();
    getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, (Plugin)this);
    new HelpCommand(this);
  }
```

In the onEnable section, I tried to call the command but it did not seem to do much help to me.

Comment: on which of these lines are you getting the error

Comment: Well, that wasn't the line of code that I had a problem with. I had a problem with the line `if (strings[0].equalsIgnoreCase("help")) {`.

Comment: As an aside, when `getNoPermissionMessage()` is called, should the resulting chat message have the color RED or GRAY? (i.e. this method and its caller are poorly constructed).

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found your problem in your onCommand method you have

```
strings.length()!=1
```

however, in order to get the length of java object arrays, you must use .length so just replace that line with

```
if (strings.length != 1) {
```

and you should be good!

Edit

Ok I now realize that it was the other way around
So since your "strings" variable is just a single String you can't do strings[0] 
all you need to do is

```
strings.equalsIgnoreCase("help")
```

Comment: Well, that wasn't the line of code that I had a problem with. I had a problem with the line `if (strings[0].equalsIgnoreCase("help")) {`.

Comment: oh ok strings isn't an array so you don't need [0]